# Constructing a line based ByteBuffer from an uint8List on-line

Tags: sockets, dart, buffer

I guess my problem is simple but I'm new to dart...

**Situation**

- On the client side I have an open socket, listening.
- The server sends data chunks of arbitrary length (In reality between 2 and 1024 bytes per chunk)
- Everytime new data arrives, it gets added to a list (uint8List)
- The connection may stay open for a longer period of time and there may be "lots" of data chunks coming in

This is only basic code and working.

```dart
main() async {
  await SecureSocket.connect('SERVER', 123).then(handleResponse);
}

void handleResponse(SecureSocket ss) {

  print('Connected to: '
      '${ss.remoteAddress.address}:${ss.remotePort}');

  ss.listen(
      (data) {
          print ('New chunk available:' + data.lengthInBytes.toString() + ' Bytes');
          String msg = String.fromCharCodes(data).trim();
          print(data.toString());
      },
      onDone: () {
          ss.destroy();
      },
      onError: (error) {
        print('An Error occured while communicating with the server.');
      },
      cancelOnError: true,
  );

  ss.write('FGG1223' + '\r\n');
}
```

Now, I want to *incrementally update* my front end with the *incoming data*.
That's why I want to start parsing and processing the data as soon as it arrives.

From a semantic point of view the delimiter in the data is **CRLF** [13,10].
It separates the command sequences from each other eg.:
**CMD1CMD2CRLFCMD3CRLF**

So, my idea was to store the arriving data line-based, separated by the CRLF in another buffer (ByteBuffer List).
The data would be much easier to process (feeding the parser) and I could update the front-end much earlier.

**Problem**

- I want to process the data on-line (on arrival). That's why I can't wait for the whole data to come in
- One chunk may have more then 1 delimiter sequences (See example response 0)
- The delimiter sequence (CRLF) may be split between 2 or more responses (See example response 1 and 2)

In this case I have to wait until the next LF arrives with one of the next chunks or throw an exception if the LF doesn't arrive after n chunks.

Is there an easy and elegant way of accomplishing this in dart?

Thank you.

**Example server response at time 0,1,2**:
0 Chunk: [32, 79, 101, 97, 100, **13**, **10**, 121, 46, **13**, **10**]
1 Chunk: [70, 76, 65, 71, **13**]
2 Chunk: [**10**, 66, 89, 69, 32, **13**, **10**]

Answer (score 0):

I know my suggested solution does not match 100% with you requirements but I hope it will still give some inspiration to a solution. Instead of writing all the logic of handling the splitting of data chunks I have made this example using methods from the Dart SDK:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

Future<void> main() async {
  await SecureSocket.connect('SERVER', 123).then(handleResponse);
}

void handleResponse(SecureSocket ss) {
  print('Connected to: ${ss.remoteAddress.address}:${ss.remotePort}');

  ss
      .map((uint8list) => uint8list.toList())
      .transform(const Utf8Decoder())
      .transform(const LineSplitter())
      .listen(
    (line) {
      print('New line available:' + line);
    },
    onDone: () {
      ss.destroy();
    },
    onError: (Exception error) {
      print('An Error occured while communicating with the server.');
    },
    cancelOnError: true,
  );

  ss.write('FGG1223\r\n');
}
```

First, I want to note that the use of the `map` method are used to convert from `Uint8List` (which are used by the `SecureSocket` class) to a normal `List` which are used by `Utf8Decoder`. I hope this would be unnecessary in future Dart releases since it seem a bit silly.

Then I convert the received bytes to UTF8 and sending it to a `LineSplitter` which returns lines from the chunk.

All of this works as data is received. So you `listen` method are triggered each time a full line has been parsed.

Again, this is not completely like you wanted. But I hope it gives some inspiration to a working solution. And if you want to make something more specific to your requirements you can take a look into how to make you own `StreamTransformer`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wasn't aware of the StreamTransformer thing. I think i will end up writing the lexer part on my own because LineSplitter() is not configurable in any kind which makes it useless for my intentions.